# RetainCycle with Globals

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

Let's say in iOS we have:

In W2AppDelegate.m:

```
GlobalViewController *globalVc;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
...

}
```

In SomeOtherViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [globalVc doSomething^{
       [globalVc.someVariable doSomethingElse]; // Is there a retain cycle here?
    }];
}
```

Is there a retain cycle here since we have a strong reference to globalVc inside the block.

globalVc -> block -> globalVc

Comment: I think everybody below is saying that this: "globalVc -> block -> globalVc" is a cycle, but that depends on: "globalVc -> block" being true in your code, which is unclear from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a retain cycle here since we have a strong reference to globalVc inside the block.

No. Because Blocks capture local variables only.

```
[globalVc doSomething^{
   [globalVc.someVariable doSomethingElse]; // Is there a retain cycle here?
}];
```

`globalVc` wasn't captured by the block because `globalVc` is global variable. No local variables here, So the block doesn't capture any objects, Thus the block doesn't retain any objects at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the bad design - it depends.

If you store a block in an ivar and that block references the object that the ivar is on then you will indeed get a retain cycle - see below:

[image]

If you do not actually store the block but you are instead just invoking the block then you'll end up with the possibility that no additional retain is taken at all - see below

[image]

---

It's not clear if your `GlobalViewController` is a singleton or just a global reference that can be updated. If it's a singleton then retain cycles are less of a concern as you expect the object to live for the life of the program anyway.

Comment: globalViewController is a singleton in this case.

Comment: Then technically the retain cycle is a non issue as the singleton will live for the life of the program anyway. But it's important to understand when/why there could be retain cycles to as it's bad practice to have cycles

Comment: so technically there is a retain cycle regardless if it's an issue?

Comment: In this particular case see `Kazuki Sakamoto`'s answer. Because it's  global variable no copy is taken.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your globalVc variable as a global variable in your app delegate. An When you create a `GlobalViewController` it will persist for the life of you application. Sometimes you want a view controller to persist forever.

That's not a retain cycle, but it does tie up memory for the life of your app.

If you are only using it for doing tasks like executing blocks, and never display it's content view to the screen, you should probably make the class something other than a view controller.

I will sometimes create a Utils singleton that I use to provide app-wide utility functions. I write an accessor function like

```
+(Utils *) sharedUtils;
```

That returns a pointer to the Utils singleton. That's cleaner than using a global like you're doing.